# How to get index in case of nested for-loops in django template?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

In my django template code, I've written code for table in nested for loops. By using with statement, I want to put serial number. But it is not working. Have a look at my code in html file:

```
<tbody>
    {% for a_testcases in testcases %}

        {% for a_test in a_testcases %}
        {% with x=forloop.parentcounter.counter %}
            <tr>
                <td id="sno_{{a_test.id}}">{{ forloop.counter|add:x }}</td>
                <td id="name_{{a_test.id}}">{{ a_test.name }}</td>
                <td id="cputime_{{a_test.id}}">{{ a_test.safe_exec.cpu_time }}</td>
                <td id="clocktime_{{a_test.id}}">{{ a_test.safe_exec.clock_time }}</td>
                <td id="memorylimit_{{a_test.id}}">{{ a_test.safe_exec.memory }}</td>
                <td id="stacksize_{{a_test.id}}">{{ a_test.safe_exec.stack_size }}</td>
                <td id="child_{{a_test.id}}">{{ a_test.safe_exec.child_processes }}</td>
                <td id="openfiles_{{a_test.id}}">{{ a_test.safe_exec.open_files }}</td>
                <td id="maxfilesize_{{a_test.id}}">{{ a_test.safe_exec.file_size }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

It is showing nothing in place of serial number.How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try `{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}` ?

Comment: that only gives the count of parent loop. If I use it, I won't get exact serial numbers.

Comment: I tried to get the exact serial number but I couldn't figure it out. One hack I thought is like "Testcase 1.1 .... Testcase 1.n then Testcase 2.1 .... Testcase 2.n .... upto n testcases".